# Magus : pool strike - arcing(SU) and attack of opportunity

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magus

Pool Strike, Arcing

> Benefit: The magus can expend 1 additional point from his arcane pool when using the pool strike arcana. If his attack hits, the magus can target a number of enemies within 15 feet equal to his Intelligence modifier (minimum 0) with a ranged touch attack as a free action. Those struck take the same energy damage as the primary target of the pool strike, including increased damage on a critical hit.

Supernatural abilities

By RAW

> " Supernatural abilities are magical and go away in an antimagic field but are not subject to spell resistance, counterspells, or to being dispelled by dispel magic. Using a supernatural ability is a standard action unless noted otherwise. Supernatural abilities may have a use limit or be usable at will, just like spell-like abilities. However, supernatural abilities do not provoke attacks of opportunity and never require Concentration checks.

**Does the ranged touch attack by "pool strike, Arcing" provokes attack of opportunity, or not, from enemies in range?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes**, it will cause. Not from the Supernatural ability, but from the *ranged touch attack*.
All ranged touch attacks cause attacks of opportunity because they are ranged attacks.

> **When you cast a spell that allows you to make a ranged touch attack, such as scorching ray, and an enemy is within reach, do you provoke two attacks of opportunity?**
>
> Yes, you provoke two attacks of opportunity, one for casting the spell and one for making a ranged attack, since these are two separate events. As a note, since all of the rays are fired simultaneously (in the case of scorching ray), you would only provoke one attack of opportunity for making the ranged attack, even if you fired more than one ray.

[FAQ Source](http://paizo.com/paizo/blog/v5748dyo5ldw0?The-FAQ-That-Time-Forgot)